# how to keep track of certain events, e.g. when queues,consumers are created and deleted?

Tags: apache-pulsar

how to keep track of certain events, e.g. when queues,consumers are created and deleted ?
similarity to rabbitmq-event-exchange (https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-event-exchange)

I have 30000 topic,if the consumer information of the queue is directly obtained through the interface, the data volume will be large and the performance will be poor. It is best to subscribe to consumer creation and deletion events like rabbitmq event exchange.